# Python script to harvest tweets to a MongoDb works with users but not hashtags. Any ideas why not?

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter

I'm playing around the Twitter API and am in the process of developing a script to pull all Tweets with a certain hashtag down to a local mongoDB. I have it working fine when I'm downloading tweets from users, but when downloading tweets from a hashtag I get:

```
return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Can anyone offer their infinite wisdom into how I could get this script to work?

To run, save it as a .py file, cd to the folder and run:

```
python twitter.py
```

Code:

```
__author__ = 'Tom Cusack'

import pymongo
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib2, json
import sys, argparse, time 

def oauth_header(url, consumer, token):

    params =  {'oauth_version': '1.0',
    'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
    'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
    }
    req = oauth.Request(method = 'GET',url = url, parameters = params)
    req.sign_request(oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(),consumer, token)
    return req.to_header()['Authorization'].encode('utf-8')

def main():
    ### Twitter Settings
    numtweets = '32000'
    verbose = 'store_true'
    retweet = 'store_false'
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'M7Xu9Wte0eIZvqhb4G9HnIn3G'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'c8hB4Qwps2aODQUx7UsyzQuCRifEp3PKu6hPQll8wnJGIhbKgZ'
    ACCESS_TOKEN = '3213221313-APuXuNjVMbRbZpu6sVbETbgqkponGsZJVT53QmG'
    ACCESS_SECRET = 'BJHrqWC9ed3pA5oDstSMCYcUcz2pYF3DmJ7jcuDe7yxvi'
    base_url = url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?include_entities=true&count=200&q=#mongodb&include_rts=%s' % (retweet)
    oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key = CONSUMER_KEY, secret = CONSUMER_SECRET)
    oauth_token = oauth.Token(key = ACCESS_TOKEN, secret = ACCESS_SECRET)

    ### Mongodb Settings
    uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/SARKY'
    if uri != None:
        try: 
            conn = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
            print 'Pulling Tweets..'
        except:
            print 'Error: Unable to connect to DB. Check uri variable.'
            return
        uri_parts = pymongo.uri_parser.parse_uri(uri)
        db = conn[uri_parts['database']]
        db['twitter-harvest'].ensure_index('id_str')

    ### Helper Variables for Harvest
    max_id = -1
    tweet_count = 0
    stream = 0

    ### Begin Harvesting
    while True:
        auth = oauth_header(url, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)
        headers = {"Authorization": auth}
        request = urllib2.Request(url, headers = headers)
        try:
            stream = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
            if err.code == 404:
                print 'Error: Unknown user. Check --user arg'
                return
            if err.code == 401:
                print 'Error: Unauthorized. Check Twitter credentials'
                return
        tweet_list = json.load(stream)

        if len(tweet_list) == 0:
            print 'No tweets to harvest!'
            return
        if 'errors' in tweet_list:
            print 'Hit rate limit, code: %s, message: %s' % (tweets['errors']['code'], tweets['errors']['message'])
            return
        if max_id == -1:
            tweets = tweet_list
        else:
            tweets = tweet_list[1:]
            if len(tweets) == 0:
                print 'Finished Harvest!'
                return

        for tweet in tweets:
            max_id = id_str = tweet['id_str']
            try:
                if tweet_count == numtweets:
                    print 'Finished Harvest- hit numtweets!' 
                    return 
                if uri != None:
                    db[user].update({'id_str':id_str},tweet,upsert = True)
                else:
                    print tweet['text']
                tweet_count+=1
                if verbose == True and uri != None:
                    print tweet['text']
            except Exception, err:
                print 'Unexpected error encountered: %s' %(err)
                return    
        url = base_url + '&max_id=' + max_id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except SystemExit as e:
        if e.code == 0:
            pass
```

Comment: The line of code 'return loads(fp.read()....' is not shown in your code above, the exception tells you where that code is.  The error tells you that 'fp' is an integer but should be a file type object (I believe).  Is the code you use to download users the same just with different parameters or is it different to the one you use for tags?

Answer (score 0):

You initially set `stream = 0`. When your `try...except` block catches a HTTP response with a code that isn't 404 or 401, `stream` is still equal to `0`, but your `except` block doesn't break out of the function.

I'd look more closely at what this response says.